# Free email address extractor

Tags: windows, gratis, html

I am looking for a software or an add-on to automatically extract email addresses from a website.

Requirements:

- free
- search entire website or a single page
- gets the pattern of the email address in the page for example (`*[at]*.*`)
- for Microsoft Windows

Comment: How can those emails be distinguished in the page? Can you give an example?

Comment: Are you talking about POP/IMAP redirection?

Comment: No Pop/IMap, this software would simply extract any pattern in a webpage which match the email (one can give the pattern too), I need it to harvest the emails in a website

Comment: Are you asking for an harvester? Hope you're not collecting them for spammy reasons? // @Cornelius I've just edited Ahmad's post to make it clearer: he's just after the addresses, like `johndoe@example.com`, if I got that right.

Comment: @Izzy Yes a harvester, I want it to extract emails of some  university websites to do a survey, I could check the pages and find the emails but it would take too long.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Email auto extractor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-auto-extractor/blkpobilpealkkcibgcgfmflneafkkah?hl=en). It is available as a chrome extension & when you view a page it can retrieve all the email addresses on that page as you had asked.

Answer (score 3):

I developed a new extension for Chrome - [Email Extractor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-extractor/jdianbbpnakhcmfkcckaboohfgnngfcc?hl=en) recently which does this job, as of now this extension won't capture the email ids having [at], or [dot] etc ....

**About the extension** :

Email Extractor is a Powerful email extraction extension for your Chrome. Extension automatically fetches valid available email ids from the web page which further you can copy paste particular email ids you need or export all of them to a text file

**Features** :

- Extract Email Address from Web Pages Automatically
- Extracts Emails on Ajax Pages as well, for example Google Search
- Extracts Cloaked Emails
- Filters for Duplicate Email ID, so you get only Unique ones
- Local Storage
- Export Option to export list of your extracted emails to a text file
- Offline Support (as of v1.6 Beta)
- Extract Emails from Local HTML Documents
- Extract Emails from Text Files
- Stores all extracted emails to storage (As of v3)

---

Sample Screenshot

[image: Email Extractor for Chrome]

Answer (score 0):

We introduce a unique and powerful tool that is capable to extract email ids from list of websites, a particular web page, website and linked web pages. The software named as [website email extractor](http://www.onedotsolution.com/web-email-extractor.aspx). It can extract emails from LinkedIn accounts and create a huge list.

Software features: 
Extract Email IDs from Websites
Extract Email IDs from All the Pages of Same Domain
Extract Email IDs from Another linked websites in same domain
Save Extracted Email IDs in .txt or .csv format
[image]
See the screen shot of the software.

Answer (score -1):

MonocomSoft introduces the fast email extractor tools to extract emails from multiple sources. You can choose [Advanced Online Email Extractor](https://www.monocomsoft.com/advanced-online-email-extractor.html) to grab emails from multiple websites or URLs. In this tool, you can use files to list a complete website or you can add websites manually. This tool can extract a large number of emails very quickly. Apart from this, with the help of this tool, data can be easily extracted from search engines. In addition, the extracted data can be refined on multiple parameters. And the extracted data can be saved in TXT and CSV file formats.

Comment: Welcome Lovepreet.  Your post has been flagged as spam.  We have a strict requirement that you *must* disclose any and all affiliations you have with any software you are recommending.  Please edit your answer to clearly and honestly disclose any affiliation you have with this product.  Please place that disclosure at the top of your post.  Thank you, and again, welcome.