# Email Scraper that also scrapes Meta Data

Tags: email, scraping

I'm trying to compile a list of email addresses of Deans of universities in the U.S.

This is to send them an important policy email to help shape U.S. higher-education policy.

I'm looking for an open-source, free, scraper / crawler software that will scrape publicly visible email addresses on university sites, and also scrape meta data (i.e., an associated title -- e.g., Dean). This way, after the scraping is over, I can quickly parse out all the email addresses with the word "Dean" attached to them.

Suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Free email address extractor](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3799/free-email-address-extractor)

Answer (score 1):

Try [website email extractor](http://www.onedotsolution.com/web-email-extractor.aspx) that is capable to extract email from a websites, webpages, list of websites etc. you can extract emails from university's website. It can extract emails from LinkedIn also.
See the picture.[image]